# Should look-up tables be included in a conceptual database model?

Tags: database-design

Should look-up tables be included on a UML conceptual database model? (I will include them on my logical model).

For example, if I'm dealing with a database that records details of projects my team is involved in... and there is a known list of 'project status' - would:

PROJECT (1..1) -> HAS -> (1..1) PROJECT_STATUS be valid?

(The PROJECT_STATUS entity will only store an ID and a status description when implemented physically)

Cheers,
Mitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The implementation detail of how project statuses are stored is not important to understanding the *Concept* that you're storing objects of type 'project' in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply grant7bar7.